# evaluate().singleNodeValue return null in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, range

I'm using `Range` and `XPATH` to retreive, save and rebuild position in html files. to rebuild range, i'm using `document.evaluate().singleNodeValue`, the problem is that singleNodeValue is returning null on firefox, it work well on chrome. Any idea why ? here my code:

```
fonction rebuildRange(xpath){

    var selectionDetails = xpathh;
    selectionDetails = selectionDetails.split(/\|/g);
    var range = oDoc.createRange();
    var selectionDetails0 = selectionDetails[0];
    selectionDetails0 = selectionDetails0.replace(/\//g, "/h:");
    selectionDetails0 = selectionDetails0.replace("h:t", "t");
    var selectionDetails2 = selectionDetails[2];
    selectionDetails2 = selectionDetails2.replace(/\//g, "/h:");
    selectionDetails2 = selectionDetails2.replace("h:t", "t");

    range.setStart(oDoc.evaluate(selectionDetails0, oDoc, nsResolver, 9, null).singleNodeValue, Number(selectionDetails[1]));
    range.setEnd(oDoc.evaluate(selectionDetails2, oDoc, nsResolver, 9, null).singleNodeValue, Number(selectionDetails[3]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testcase [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjJpP/) works for me in Chrome and FireFox

```
var x = document.evaluate("/html/body", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
console.log(x.singleNodeValue);
```

However, trying the same from FireBug does nothing, and the web console in FireFox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) gives `null` on some pages and works on others.

Most likely something weird going on with *Security/Origin* here; are you running the script in-page, loading an external resource (same domain) or loading from a different domain?

Try putting a *function* which actually calls `document.evaluate` in a `<script>` in the `<head>` and use that instead of `document.evaluate`. e.g. open *FireBug* and run `de('/html/body').singleNodeValue;` on [**this page**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjJpP/1/show/) which has the following in `<head>`

```
function de(xp) {
    return document.evaluate(xp, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i'm loading from external resource. The example you give work well, but i'm working with xpath like `/h:HTML[1]/h:BODY[1]/h:A[2]/h:P[1]/text()[1]`, maybe this `[n]` is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, i get it: the error was coming from this two lines

```
selectionDetails0 = selectionDetails0.replace(/\//g, "/h:");
selectionDetails0 = selectionDetails0.replace("h:t", "t");
```

and the `nsResolver`, firefox doesn't accept xpath with `resolver`, that's why `document.evalute()` return `empty set` and then `singleNodeValue` return `null`.
I just delete the two lines and replace `nsResolver` by `null` and every think work well, right now, if anybody is seeing errors coming without `resolver` let me know please ...